# Can I undelete my own self-deleted post?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

For editing let's say comments in Stack Overflow, one has 5 minutes to do so. How does it work for deleting posts? Is there a time limit to undelete a post that one has deleted or can it be undeleted any time desired after post deletion?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I tried deleting and then undeleting it in a few minutes, being worried that my post will be gone forever! I didn't want to risk waiting for longer, so I preferred asking before doing so! (:

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can undelete a self-deleted post at any time. There is no time limit.

You can't undelete a moderator deleted post. If you think it was unfairly deleted flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: If so why can't I see my own deleted by me question?

Comment: @Eliyahu - you can if you have the link, but they're not listed anywhere.

Comment: That's the problem :)

Comment: But I finally found it in my recent activities list

Comment: I stumble upon someone else mentioning browser history. That's where I found mine. I just wanted to hide a question while I confirmed I really wanted to ask it, so I deleted it thinking I'd have easy access to undelete it later.