# Can I delete my own question after undeleting it?

Tags: discussion, edits, deleted-questions, undeleted-questions

All who failed in trying to change the reason for a close request given a post (after retracting the request you are not able to apply another close request) will share the fear to hit the *undelete* button on a self-deleted question that there will be a similar lock.

[image]

This decision can give you a serious headache if the deletion was done to protect sensitive information and the recovery is for the only purpose of saving the contents of the last edit state (as markdown) for yourself privately (the edit function is disabled for deleted questions).

I found the comparable [Can I undelete my own self-deleted post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262294/2932052) and its answer that encouraged me to undelete (due to a misunderstanding: the limit asked for was a time limit, not a counter) and so I learned that I was able to delete my post again after undeleting.

Is there any maximum count of delete/undelete actions on own posts?

Comment: "_deletion was done to protect sensitive information_" that might not work as people with 10k rep can see deleted posts. Instead you should flag to have your post redacted. See [How to handle a publicly posted API key (or password, or other sensitive information)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258066/how-to-handle-a-publicly-posted-api-key-or-password-or-other-sensitive-informa)

Comment: Those of us with [moderation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete) can easily find recently deleted posts if I so wanted to; and that would include the sensitive data that was exposed. As far as I know, however, there is no limit on delete and undelete votes/actions; though the mods have now stated if you vote to (un)delete a post more than once they will see it as "abuse" due to the fact that you can do so (this likely doesn't apply to your own posts, but still be careful).

Comment: @Larnu I had to add another undelete-delete cycle to remove the sensitive information from the post (hopefully not seen as "abuse"), now I flagged it for moderator intervention.

Comment: @Wolf no it's not counted as abuse. See the 2nd point in the rule [Why am I not allowed to vote to delete or undelete a post more than once?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407953/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-vote-to-delete-or-undelete-a-post-more-than-once): "_This rule does not apply to the post author deleting or undeleting their own post._"

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for pointing out the difference (I already saw). On the other hand, I would expect that people who repeatedly delete and restore their posts without there being an obvious reason for doing so will draw the ire of the moderators.

Comment: Are you talking about questions or answers or either? There's a general FAQ about deleting on MSE. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that since you talk about closing, I'm guessing that you mean questions. There's limits to when questions can be deleted (see FAQ) but it doesn't consider whether it has been deleted previously.

Comment: I can't tell you whether or not there's something else preventing undeletion without knowing what the post you're talking about is. *In general* it's definitely true, so I'm not sure why you're unable to edit.

Comment: i tried it and i had no problem, maybe it is a Privilege that you are still missing.

Comment: @Wolf That part says "Self-deleted ___answers___" not _questions_. I have if my memory serves me right edited my own deleted answer previously when I did not have 10k rep yet.

Comment: @Wolf yes, [due to spammers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296102/241919).

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes I realized the little difference. I remember that I read that but, for some reason, it was blown away in the next sentence. I rephrased these details so that future readers (with bad eyes and memory like me) have an easier job.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you were able to unilaterally delete it before, you should be able to delete it again (barring intervention by other users). The [deletion rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) are the same:

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - has only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes
> - has no bounties that were awarded to any answer that isn't already deleted

(More rules not mentioned here are that it can't have an active bounty or be locked, or [a couple of other things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/323179).)

To prevent other users from stopping you from being able to delete again, have your edit ready so the question isn't undeleted for long. You can double check your formatting by pasting it into a new post (don't accidentally submit though).

Note:

- The new (moderator enforced) policy on not being able to delete or undelete more than once only applies when voting to delete *another* user's post: [Why am I not allowed to vote to delete or undelete another user's post more than once?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407953/6083675)
- Self deleted posts are [not listed in the 10k tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292531/323179) but they can be viewed by 10k users with the link.  If you needed something sensitive to be redacted, deleting is an ok first step, but you should also flag for a moderator to perform a redaction or change your credentials, if possible.

Comment: That there is a need to **have your edit ready** is a bit of a usability nightmare I think. This [spam protection thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296102/238205) could certainly have been done differently. Too bad.

Comment: @Wolf If you are concerned about sensitive information, you can flag the question for moderator attention instead and request a redaction, rather than trying to delete, edit, and undelete. That will serve to actually protect said sensitive information, whereas a simple edit by yourself will not accomplish much (since revision history is visible to everyone).

Comment: @TylerH How exactly do I *flag for moderator intervention*, I thought that I just did it?

Comment: @Wolf You click the "flag" button below the post. It is usually right next to the "delete" button. There last option on the flag modal that pops up is "flag for moderator attention" with a free text box for you to describe your request/concern.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks a lot, done. I hope that I did it right now (also deleting it to restrict the accessibility to a minimum).

Comment: @TylerH seems there is no difference between the two options, I had to retract the first one to raise the second. And now the text isn't better :-( let's see how it turns out...

Comment: @Wolf Moderator flags are not automatically handled; moderators have to see them and act on them... and redaction requires two moderators to perform. It takes time.